# How do I can configure Firefox and Terminal via internet Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, command-line, firefox, proxy

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 and with I've broadband connection setup but it's only some application via internet , But I can't access Firefox and Terminal via internet see screenshot , when Firefox running then showing me message proxy detect, How I can solve this issue anyone help me ?

Terminal Proxy

I've edit /etc/bash.bashrc file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Adding two line below, but I don't know here username & password, Broadband connection setup username & password same proxy server ? Confusion here

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

Save and exit the file, Still I can't access this command

`sudo apt-get update`
 when run this command then show message(screenshot)

[image]